# Is it possible to delegate an HTTP request transparently?

Tags: http, redirect, request

Suppose computer A sends an HTTP request to a server B, and B wants C to answer it. Is it possible for C to send a response back to A without B intervention and without specific actions from A (as with a 3xx redirection)? Suppose C may not have a public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

That's what a `reverse proxy` would do. Depending what platform you are on, there are a lot of options.

One way that works on many platforms is e.g. `node-http-proxy` that you could start on server B. In the most simple case, this one-liner would do:

```
require('http-proxy').createServer(81, 'serverb').listen(80);
```

It listens on port 80 and redirects to port 81 on serverb.

See https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy for more options.

Of course, there are lots of well-established proxies with a lot more bells and whistles (although node-http-proxy can do https tunneling etc. as well), but configuring those can be more challenging that running this one-liner. It all depends on your use case.

**Edit**: Reading your comment, this can be done using **direct routing**. Your question is about HTTP (layer 7), and as *direct routing* works on a lower layer, higher-level protocols like HTTP work as well. Quote from http://horms.net/projects/has/html/node9.html:

> **Direct Routing**: Packets from clients are forwarded directly to the
>   back-end server. The IP packet is not modified, so the back-end
>   servers must be configured to accept traffic for the virtual server's
>   IP address. This can be done using a dummy interface, or packet
>   filtering to redirect traffic addressed to the virtual server's IP
>   address to a local port. The back-end server may send replies directly
>   back to the client. That is if a host based layer 4 switch is used, it
>   may not be in the return path.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In a reverse proxy, isn't it needed an intervention of server B to send back the response from C to A? I was expecting this dialog: A says "Hello, B!", B says "Hey, C, A is saying hello", C says "Hi, A, my name is B. What can I do for you?"